# Where to place Structs and Enums in C++ class + final constants

Tags: c++

I have started reading C++ and I have a question about classes and member variables of type Enum and Struct. Where should I declare Enums/Structs so that I can use them as member variables when I separate header and implementation file? And also, how can I make a final member variable in a C++ class? I am just getting compilation error when adding `const int myTest` as a member variable, where should I initialize them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header file is like a person saying 'I can do this, that and the other' - so put declarations into it - enums, structs, class declarations, constants, ...

The implementation file is like a person saying 'I can do this and this is how I can do it' - it produces a recipe - Actual machine code for the CPU to crunch.

`const` says - do not change me. To intialise in a class you need:

```
class X
{
  private:
     const int y;
  public:
     X() : y(5) {}
};
```

for example. If you are learning about C++ `const` is a very useful tool to prevent you making a multitude of errors.

Comment: Thank you Ed. So the X() : y(5) {} shall only be in the declaration?

Comment: It's rare to make a member variable const, without also making it static however.  And a `static const` variable is defined completely differently.

Answer (score 5):

the simplest solution is to simple declare the enums & structs directly before the class they are a member of:

```
struct Gizmo
{
  int n_;
};

class Foo
{
public: 
  Gizmo gizmo_;
};
```

If `Gizmo` is logically coupled to `Foo` (eg, if you would never use a `Gizmo` outside the context of using a `Foo`), it might also make sense to make `Gizmo` a nested class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  struct Gizmo
  {
    int n_;
  };

  Gizmo gizmo_;
};
```

If you want to instantiate a `Gizmo` declared this way, you can resolve the scope yourself:

```
Foo::Gizmo gizmo;
```

Finally, if `Gizmo` and `Foo` are not logically coupled, and you might use `Gizmo`s all over the place without needing a `Foo`, then it probably belongs in its own header file.

### gizmo.h

```
struct Gizmo
{
  int n_;
};
```

### foo.h

```
#include "gizmo.h"
class Foo
{
public: 
  Gizmo gizmo_;
};
```

Comment: wierd, the second block of code isn't rendering as code on this page, but it does on the edit page for me.

Comment: You also don't mention the const member thing

Answer (score 3):

> Where should I declare Enums/Structs so that I can use them as member variables when I separate header and implementation file?

You must declare them before their use, that is. before the declaration of the member in the class of their type. Either:

- you define them in their own header file and `#include` that file in your class' header file (before the declaration of your class)
- or you define them just before your class
- or you define them in your class before the members

> I am just getting compilation error when adding const int myTest as a member variable, where should I initialize them?

In the constructor, using initializers. Ie.:

```
Clazz::Clazz() : my_const_var(0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to add an enum or struct as a member variable of the class, the definition of the enum or struct must be complete before you declare the member. This can either be inside the class, outside of the class but coming before it in the .h header, or in a different .h header that is included before or within the current one.

There shouldn't be any problem declaring a member variable as const, but it places a restriction on how it must be initialized. You must do it in the initializer list of the constructor.

```
MyClass::MyClass() : myTest(value)
{
}
```

Comment: `but coming before it in...` is oddly worded, maybe that should be `but defined before the it is used in...`